# bitbake how it copies specified recipes to rootfs

Tags: bitbake

An example while run

> $ bitbake foo

then the intall path as below such as

> tmp-glibc/xxx/.../foo/git-r0/image/

What I need is which `bitbake` command will copy  `tmp-glibc/xxx/.../foo/git-r0/image/` to `target-image` for next build filesystem (eg, ext4). such as

> $ bitbake -b build-target-image -c do_makesystem

Answer (score 0):

this command does **copy all recipes** to target rootfs folder for build filesystem

> **bitbake -f target-image -c rootfs**

But is it possible to copy specified recipe only?